# I want to show a range of in Cell using another column but not exactly named ranges

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So basically, what I am trying to do is in column C is, I want show that it is 20% of B - 30% of B.

[image]

For Example, take C2,

I want to show it as "100 - 150".

PS: When I say "100 - 500", I don't mean 100 minus 500, I want to show it as a range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula

```
=B2*20% & "-" & B2*30%
```

For array approach.

```
=INDEX(IF(LEN(B2:B),B2:B*20% & "-" & B2:B*30%,""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Array

> **Paste** this on `C2` no need to drag down take a look at this [**Example Sheet**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c0gXMsJJpNPVdzfv_G-BWzfqaYYmoYE-9tzOSjFXPLk/edit?usp=sharing)

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,CONCAT(CONCAT(A2:A*20%," - "),A2:A*30%)))
```

[image]

### Cell

> **Paste** this on `C2` in a single cell

```
=CONCAT(CONCAT(A2*20%," - "),A2*30%)
```

))

[image]